# Exchange server email sync

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, email, exchange, outlook

I have just upgraded to ICS on my Galaxy s2 and have an Outlook Exchange account that I sync on the device. Prior to the ICS update, when I read emails on my computer it automatically updated the device as that same email being read. Now I have to manually mark all my phone emails as read even though I have read them on my computer.

Is there a setting I can change back to so I don't have to do this?